# Add AS3 worker Flex 4.6

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-builder, flex4.6, worker

i try to use worker library in flex SDK to create true multi-threaded applications , i using Flash Builder version 4.6 and i update my Adobe AIR to 3.7 .
What is the steps to using workers library inside my SDK ?

Comment: Is this a mobile project? If it is, you can't use Workers (as of AIR 3.7, at least)

Comment: not mobile project , desktop project , i have many problem when trying to install it .

Comment: Could you actually describe those problems? We can't help if we don't know what you're doing or experiencing.

Comment: iam not doing anything , i want to know how to using it , because its not in my Adobe Air SDK